# How to correctly use VAVR collections to be thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, vavr

VAVR collections are "immutable".

So, if I have static variable, for example, holding all the WebSocket sessions, how would I use VAVR so that the collection is thread safe?

For example:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {

    private static Set<Session> sessions = //???; // how should I initialize this?

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        sessions = sessions.add(session); // is this OK???
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        sessions = sessions.remove(session); // is this OK??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap the immutable vavr collection in an atomically updatable [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html), and use one of its update methods to atomically update the reference to the immutable collection.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {

    private static AtomicReference<Set<Session>> sessionsRef = 
            new AtomicReference<>(HashSet.empty());

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        sessionsRef.updateAndGet(sessions -> sessions.add(session));
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        sessionsRef.updateAndGet(sessions -> sessions.remove(session));
    }

}
```

Make sure you read the javadoc of [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) if you are going to use them in other scenarios, as there are some requirements on the update functions that need to be respected to get correct behavior.

Comment: in close should be remove?